# Can you use Dask distributed from an existing MPI job where the data is already partitioned?

Tags: dask-distributed

I have a running MPI job on a cluster where the data is already partitioned across all MPI ranks. Is is possible to use Dask in this modality?

Other noteworthy constraints:

Redistributing the data can be problematic since it is possible that the available memory is limited.